# Disable controls in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can I disable all controls in MPMoviecontoller so that user even not able to identify that a video is being played. Even I don't want to show controls when user tap on the video. Any help is appreciated. 
This is my code:

```
self.myMovieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[[self.myMovieController view] setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.myMovieController view].backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.myMovieController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
self.myMovieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeHidden;
self.myMovieController.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
self.myMovieController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.view addSubview: [self.myMovieController view]];
[self.myMovieController play];
```

Still the controls are visible initially for some seconds , and again when tap on the views controls become visible.

Answer (score 5):

`MPMoviePlayerController` have following control style

```
   MPMovieControlStyleNone,
   MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded,
   MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen,
   MPMovieControlStyleDefault = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
```

You can set Set `controlStyle` property of `MPMoviePlayerController`  to `MPMovieControlStyleNone`

Try to set control style in this way:

```
self.myMovieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment ,I am already using this settings , Please verify my code and comment on the same , If you find something.

Comment: @KannanPrasad in your code you written `self.myMovieController .controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeHidden;` which not make sense. i updated my answer.

Comment: ,Thanks it worked, How about my second point do have any idea , to make the controls invisible even when the user taps on the MoviePlayer

Comment: Is there a way to disable specific buttons, like Previous and Next in the video player?